# creating arrays based on contents of an array?

Tags: php, arrays, extract

I pull data from a site that I put into an array. Essentially, it's like:

```
$lines = array(Ginza, Marunouchi, Hibiya, Tozai, Chiyoda, Yurakucho)
```

It would be most convenient if I could create arrays based on these names.
So, for example, I could later do:

```
var_dump($Yurakucho);
```

Ultimately, I will be looping through $lines to pull data based on it's contents, generating a file_get_contents with lines like:

```
$info = '?rdf:type=odpt:StationTimetable&odpt:station=odpt.Station:TokyoMetro.Yurakucho.Heiwadai';
```

where 'Yurakucho' is from $lines and 'Heiwadai' is from $Yurakucho.
I've tried `$$lines = array();`, which doesn't work.  Can I use extract($lines) to create array names?

Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: Maybe you should use array like `$lines = array('Yurakucho' => array('Heiwadai', ....))`?

Comment: Where do you intend to get the values for $Yurakucho from...??

Comment: The values for $lines will be pulled from a url query, like `https://api.tokyometroapp.jp/api/v2/datapoints/odpt.Railway:TokyoMetro` and then used to make another query like `https://api.tokyometroapp.jp/api/v2/datapoints?rdf:type=odpt:StationTimetable&odpt:station=odpt.Station:TokyoMetro.Yurakucho` which will result in a timetable to be put into the array `$Yurakucho`.

Answer (score 0):

use `array_combine`. It can combine two arrays,  one will be the keys to other array. 
I think you can use this array function in this scenario.

```
$lines = array(Ginza, Marunouchi, Hibiya, Tozai, Chiyoda, Yurakucho);
$some_values=array(abc,pqr,sdf,hjk,klj,Heiwadai);
$result=array_combine($lines,$some_values);

print_r($result);
```

and then use key and value of this array

or use

```
extract($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$lines = array('Ginza', 'Marunouchi', 'Hibiya', 'Tozai', 'Chiyoda', 'Yurakucho');
$lines = array_fill_keys($lines, array());
extract($lines);
```

`var_dump($Ginza)` should give you `array(0) { }`

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 sorry I'm not following your question, $Ginza should just be an empty array. Take a look at [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

Comment: $Ginza is to be used in a second loop, where it is 'filled' with a timetable:

Answer (score 0):

Code below should solve your problem

```
$lines = array("Ginza" => array(1,2,3),
               "Marunouchi"  => array(4,5,6),
               "Hibiya" => "test3",
               "Tozai" => "test4",
               "Chiyoda" => "test5",
               "Yurakucho" => array("Heiwadai", "test6"));
extract($lines);
var_dump($lines);
var_dump($Yurakucho);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the lines will be put into an array through a url query.  So, I won't know the actual names that are in the $lines array.